# CSS removing border on tabbed navigation menu

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a simple tabbed navigation menu in CSS. I am having a hard time getting the bottom border to go away on the active tab. Normally this would not be hard to do, but I also want a line height set.. so I'm using inline-block with various IE and FF fixes. This makes it display the way I want, with the exception of the bottom border.

I have tried numerous methods for getting this to work, including setting up some operators.. but I don't know enough about CSS to determine if I was using them correctly.

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kqu45/).

(Obviously my CSS skills need work and I could probably simplify the code greatly as well.)

Code:

```
#tab_menu {
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
color: #000000;
border-bottom: #dddddd solid 1px;
}
#tab_menu ul {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}
#tab_menu li {
list-style: none;
line-height: 42px;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
font-size: 14px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
display: -moz-inline-stack;
/* Firefox Fix */
display: inline-block;
/* Normal Function */
zoom: 1;
/* IE Fix */
*display: inline;
/* IE Fix */
}
.tab_menu_active {
color: #000000;
border-bottom: none;
border-left: #dddddd solid 1px;
border-right: #dddddd solid 1px;
border-top: #dddddd solid 1px;
}
.tab_menu_active a {
color: #000000;
text-decoration: none;
}
.tab_menu_not_active {
}
.tab_menu_not_active a {
color:#52a4d4;
text-decoration: none;
}
.tab_menu_not_active:hover {
background: #eeeeee;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="tab_menu">
<ul>
    <li class="tab_menu_not_active">    <a href="">Link 1</a>

    </li>
    <li class="tab_menu_active">    <a href="">Link 2</a>

    </li>
    <li class="tab_menu_not_active">    <a href="">Link 3</a>

    </li>
    <li class="tab_menu_not_active">    <a href="">Link 4</a>

    </li>
    <li class="tab_menu_not_active">    <a href="">Link 5</a>

    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kqu45/3/)

for the #tab_menu I removed the **overflow:hidden;**

```
#tab_menu {   
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
}
```

to the .tab_menu_active I have added this styles, that will add border bottom white and with position manipulation will overidre the gray border color.

```
.tab_menu_active {   
    border-bottom:solid 1px #fff;
    position:relative; 
    top:1px;
}
.tab_menu_active a {   
    position:relative;
    top:-1px;
}
```

Comment: Well. That'll do it! I was trying to get a similar result with negative margins. Didn't think about setting something like that relative. (The overflow hidden was part of a different thing I was trying that didn't work out, so thanks for removing that as well). Thanks so much!

Comment: You can just add the position relative + the minus margin http://jsfiddle.net/kqu45/4/

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is your entire `#tab_menu` has a bottom border. There are a couple ways you could solve this, but first I'll give you some details about how to simplify your css.

Give the `li`'s the class `tab`, that means that every tab you have will all get the same css. On the active one, give it a second class, `active`. In your css definitions, define that all `tab`'s should have the same css (instead of having duplicate css in `tab_menu_active` and `tab_menu_not_active`).

I would recommend giving them all a border on the bottom, and then removing that border in the active one.

Here's a forked [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aarilight/N5ms3/).

Comment: Thanks. I will at least make those changes to reduce duplicate code. The rest of your example doesn't work exactly like I need it to. There are a few bits of code that aren't supported by older browsers, and the bottom edge no longer extends the width of the screen.

Comment: Ahkay, fair enough. Didn't realise you needed the entire bottom border. And just didn't bother having any old-browser support. You do have a working answer tho, so I won't bother updating my answer. Would have done the same thing as that one next. =)